# mysql 1932 table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql

Hi i'am new to php and sql database, i am getting this error (mysql 1932 table doesn't exist in engine) when i'am accessing the database, how can resolve this
issue i need to access rk_sourav database

I tried so many ways but i'm not find any solution

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that produces the error. Add the query as code, not an image. Also, in the list of tables in rk_sourav, do you see the table in the error message?

Comment: What does this have to do with php?